# Mount Washington Cog Railway

Tags: usa, new-england

Anyone here tried the Mt. Washington Cog Railway in New Hampshire(NH), USA? What are the advantages of taking  the cog train versus driving  up to the top?

I am going there on Oct 14th as a part of a fall foliage trip.

Relevant links:

https://www.thecog.com/

https://www.mountwashington.org/

Comment: Vote to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: What you _should_ do depends on your own personal preferences and needs: we can't choose for you. If you have a factual, objective question that we can answer, we're happy to help, but the answer to "Should I take the cog train or drive up to the top?" is "It's up to you. Do whatever you think you'd enjoy the most."

Comment: A tourist could enjoy *both* experiences.

Comment: I would love to drive just feel i would lose out on the natural beauty while being focused on driving. But anyway I guess I will take the train.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few years back my friend and I went up in that train, great experience. It was around the same time of the year and we had real snow while on the mountain.
I would take the train again, but also tell people only to drive up when experienced in driving mountain roads in snow conditions.

Also check weather conditions and road closures. I know they close that road at times but I do not know with how much snow they stay open.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks @willeke. I think I will also stick to the train. I am a good driver (or so do I believe). The only concern was $72 ticket for the train vs $31 if you drive your way up there. But looks like train is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If you bother going there, take the train.

I was there several years ago, when they still operated the kind of original steam engines, but from what I read, those are no longer in regular service, or have been rebuilt. But the experience is still it.

Just be aware, it is steep…